# What's the best way to repeat this login system for 2 users instead of 1?

Tags: python, authentication, tkinter

I'd like to be able to change this login system I have made to be ablle to authenticate 2 users compared to the current 1 user authentication. In a way so that once the first user has logged in the authentication box asks the 2nd user for their credentials to login.

Here is my current code:

```
main = Tk()
#sets the title of the main Tkinter window
main.title("Auth Box")
#defines the size of the main Tkinter window
main.geometry("225x150")
#sets the background colour to ######
main.config(bg="light sky blue")
#sets the focus to the main Tkinter window
main.focus_force()

##################################
#defines the clear_widget function
def clear_widget(event):
    #removes the text in the entry widget when the user goes to enter a username or password
    if username_box == main.focus_get() and username_box.get() == "Enter Username":
        username_box.delete(0, END)

    if password_box == main.focus_get() and password_box.get() == "     ":
        password_box.delete(0, END)

################################
#defines the repopulate function
def repopulate(event):
    #this will repopulate the username entry box with "Enter Username" if they don't enter a username after clicking on the entry box once
    if username_box != main.focus_get() and username_box.get() == "":
        username_box.insert(0, "Enter Username")

    if password_box != main.focus_get() and password_box.get() == "":
        password_box.insert(0, "     ")

###############################
#defines the passfocus function
def passfocus(event):
    password_box.focus_force()

###########################
#defines the login function
def login(*event):
#*event
    user = username_box.get()
    passw = password_box.get()
    file = open("Endgame_Spoilers.txt","r")
    Endgame_Spoilers = (file.read())
    #checks that the username is alphanumeric
    if user.isalpha():
        #if the password the user entered is equal to the one in the txt file the following code will run:
        if passw == Endgame_Spoilers:
            #sets the score variable equal to 0
            score = 0
            #sets z equal to 0 for while loop
            z = 0
            #destroys the authentication box
            main.destroy()
            #if the password entered by the user is eqaul to the one in the text file the following if statement will be executed
            if passw == Endgame_Spoilers:
                print("Player logged in successfully")

########################
#defines a 50 x  50 grid
rows = 0
while rows < 10:
    main.rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)
    main.columnconfigure(rows, weight=1)
    rows += 1

######################
#username entry widget
username_box = Entry(main, bg = "ghost white")
username_box.insert(0, "Enter Username")
#allows for the clearing of the "Enter Username" text from the entry widget
username_box.bind("<FocusIn>", clear_widget)
#allows for the repopulating of the username_box with "Enter Username" if no input is entered
username_box.bind("<FocusOut>", repopulate)
#changes focus to the password box if the enter key is pressed while focus is on the username box
username_box.bind("<Return>", passfocus)
#places the username_box entry
username_box.grid(row=1, column=5)
#forces focus to the username box
username_box.focus_force()

######################
#password entry widget
#makes the characters inputted into the password entry all * so that the password isn't visible
password_box = Entry(main, show="*", bg = "ghost white")
password_box.insert(0, "     ")
password_box.bind("<FocusIn>", clear_widget)
password_box.bind("<FocusOut>", repopulate)
#allows for the return (enter) key to be used to login or the login button
password_box.bind("<Return>", login)
password_box.grid(row=2, column=5)

#############
#login button
login_btn = Button(main, text="Login", command=login, bg = "ghost white")
login_btn.bind("<Return>", login)
login_btn.grid(row=5, column=5)

#ends the tkinter mainloop
main.mainloop()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Are you expecting two people to sit in front of a single computer and both log into the application at the same time? Once authenticated, which of them would be logged in? Why are you trying to do this? It's very likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Comment: Sorry, by 2 people logging in I mean the authentication box asking for users credentials twice on the same computer and once authenticated the 2 player game that i've made can be ran